# Re-indexing answer already on the web

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I just had a TeX-related technical issue, and unfortunately TeX.SX has no information about it.

Googling for the error message in question returns a Gentoo Forum post containing a workable (but not ideal) solution. This same forum in turn references a post in the GNU-AUCTeX mailing list, which contains a better solution, though it might still need a bit tweaking.

All in all, the solution is already there, but it's quite cumbersome, and more importantly I don't know if these forums risk losing their Google indices in the future (making them harder to find), or simply disappearing...

So I wonder, should I create a question and make a "FAQ-style" answer for it, just to get the solution indexed in TeX.SX?

This might help other users, and provide a more "stable" reference, but I'm not sure this is interesting for TeX.SX. Can someone give me some advice about it?

Answer (score 16):

My opinion is that it is perfectly normal to ask a question that is covered elsewhere on the Internet, as long as it is (La)TeX-related. In fact, even if you didn't ask the question here, it would have been answered on the main site - the community here is eager to help, regardless of the expertise/level of the question.

On a completely related topic: The Stack Exchange also allows you to [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) if you so wish. This happens from time to time, and is also an option when you know exactly what works for you, and it is applicable to a wider audience.

The seemingly opposite was asked in [Are non-SX FAQs now redundant?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3664/5764), where it was confirmed that dual resources are perfectly fine.